# Concerning the Proof that a Union of a sequence of Countable Sets is Countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Theorem 2.12 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin states that the union S of a sequence of countable sets (E<sub>n</sub>) is countable. In the proof, Rudin constucts the following array:

[image: Array of elements]

and he then iterates through it to obtain the following:

[image: Sequence]

and he concluded by stating that if any two sets have elements in common, then they appear more than once in the above sequence therefore we take a subset T of the set of all postitive integers and that subset T is equivalent to the union. Hence it is countable. To my understanding, to establish a set is countable, we must construct a 1-1 onto map from the set of positive integers(or a subset of it, T in this case) to that set. What I assume the author does here is he constructs the following function:

$$f: T ↦ S$$

$$f(n_1)=x_{11}$$
$$f(n_2)=x_{21}$$
$$f(n_3)=x_{12}$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$

where the n's are elements of T in order.

Is what I said correct? Is the function above valid?

Thank you.

Comment: What you said is exactly that Rudin is constructed by arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{tl;dr:}$ yes you are right.

You can think of an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ of elements $a_i$ of some set $A$ as a function from the set of positive integers to $A$ given by $n \mapsto a_n$ (this is in fact the formal definition of a sequence). Then the list Ruding wrote (namely $x_{11} ; x_{21} ; x_ {12} \dots$) is the same thing as giving a (surjective) function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\cup_n E_n$.

Sometimes "$A$ is countable" is defined to mean that there exists a surjection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$. This is equivalent, when $A$ is infinite, to the definition you seem to be using (i.e. that there is a $ \textit{bijection }g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$). That is basically because given a surjection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ you can restrict $f$ to some subset $T \subseteq\mathbb{N}$ so that $f|_T : T \rightarrow A$ is a bijection. And it's easy (for example using that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered) to find a bijection between $T$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Possibly interesting: if I'm not mistaken the fact that any surjection can be restricted to a bijection is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: very small nitpick, but the existence of a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to A$ is equivalent to the existence of a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to A$ only under the hypothesis that $A$ is infinite; indeed, there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ onto any finite set. it's a small point but perhaps still worth clarifying :) (+1)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Edited, thank you!

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice to show that the existence of a surjection $f : \Bbb{N} \to X$ implies the existence of an injection (provided of course that $X$ is infinite).